Does $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^k 1_{X \ge k} ]}{\mathbb{E}[X^k]} =0$ for $X \ge 0$
Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with all finite moments.
Does it hold that  $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^k 1_{ \{X \ge k \}} ]}{\mathbb{E}[X^k]} =0$$
What I Tried
This clearly holds for bounded random variables, and variables whose distributions have fast decaying tails.  However, I cannot find a general argument.

Is $X$ discrete or continous ?

Write $E[X^k]=E[X^k1_{X\geq k}]+E[X^k1_{X\leq k}]$

@EDX Let's not assume anything about the distribution of $X$.

We prove that OP's claim does not hold in general. Let $X$ have the density function of the form
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi/2} \, x} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x} \mathbf{1}[x \geq 1]. $$
Then for any $k$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X^k]
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi/2}} \int_{1}^{\infty} x^{k-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2} + ku} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{e^{k^2/2}}{\sqrt{\pi/2}} \int_{-k}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}u.
\end{align*}
This shows that $f$ is indeed a valid density function such that $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$ is finite for all $k$. Also, by a similar computation, for $k \geq 1$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X^k \mathbf{1}_{\{X \geq k\}}]
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi/2}} \int_{k}^{\infty} x^{k-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi/2}} \int_{\log k}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2} + ku} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{e^{k^2/2}}{\sqrt{\pi/2}} \int_{\log k - k}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}u.
\end{align*}
Finally, if we define $G(x) = \int_{-x}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}u$, then $G(\infty) = \sqrt{2\pi}$, and hence
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^k \mathbf{1}_{\{X \geq k\}}]}{\mathbb{E}[X^k]}
= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{G(k - \log k)}{G(k)}
= 1. $$

Here is a more natural example:

Exercise. When $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)$, show that
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^k \mathbf{1}_{\{X \geq k\}}]}{\mathbb{E}[X^k]} = \frac{1}{2}. $$
Hint. Show that the ratio can be written as $\mathbb{P}(N_k \leq k)$, where $N_t$ is the Poisson process with unit rate, and then invoke the central limit theorem.


To the downvoters: Can you please explain what needs to be improved in my answer?

So you proove it is wrong in general case ?

@EDX, Indeed, that's what I proved. :)

Sorry so, can you edit your answer with anything so I modify my vote.

@EDX Maybe I was not crystal clear about what I wanted to show in my answer. I updated my answer accordingly :)

Yes, and I sniped a lit bit fast also your post. Thanks for the adding.

This is currently not an answer but tracks
We can write it :
$$ E[X^k]=E[X^k1_{X\geq k}] + E[X^k1_{X\leq k}]$$
Then :
$$ 1=\dfrac{E[X^k1_{X\geq k}]}{E[X^k]} + \dfrac{E[X^k1_{X\leq k}]}{E[X^k]}$$
Now $X$ being non-negative and by increasing caracter of expectancy:
$$ E[X^k1_{X\leq k}]=\int X^k1_{X\leq k}dP$$
By transfer theorem on $\mathbb{R}^+$ :
$$ E[X^k1_{X\leq k}]=\int_{0}^{k}x^kf_X(x)dx$$
The question is now :
Does the following equivalence hold ? :
$$\int_{0}^{k}x^kf_X(x)dx \underset{k \to \infty}{\sim} E[X^k] $$
Under the conditions :
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)dx =1$$
$$ \forall k\geq 1, \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^kf_X(x)\triangleq M_k<+ \infty$$
What we have :

By the convergence of all moments :

$$ \forall k\geq 1, f_X(x)=\underset{x \to \infty}{o}(\dfrac{1}{x^k}) $$
(which is by the way powerful)

We suppose $X$ non-bounded (otherwise as you said it is easy)

We have because of moments to be finite, for all $k$ :


$$ x^kf_X(x) \sim_x x^k1_{x\leq k}f_X(x)$$
$$ \int_y^{\infty}x^kf_X(x) \sim_y\int_y^{\infty} x^k1_{x\leq k}f_X(x)dx$$
Hope it gives ideas.

Thanks for your thoughts. This is helpful.
